# error Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.3 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt, node-gyp

I'm trying to install bcrypt on my laptop, Windows 7 64bit.
I have already installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package, 2012 Redistributable package. Also installed Visual Studio 2013 community with update 4.

Im trying to add node module with this command `npm install bcrypt --msvs_version=2013` into my nodejs project https://github.com/steelx/nodeauth

I have already installed required Python 2.7.9 and node-gyp.
But still no luck.

Here is the full error log [here](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/issues/307)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a security firewall that was blocking download links.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a common issue. You'll need to install the 64-bit Windows SDK.

https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/#installation

Cheers!

Comment: No, actually it's my office internet security firewall issue